# How to reshape numpy array of shape (4, 1, 1) into (4, 2, 1)?

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array

```
arr = np.array([1, 4, 4, 5]).reshape((4, 1, 1))
```

Now I want to reshape `arr` into `arr1` such that

```
>>> print(arr1)
[[[1]
  [1]]
 [[4]
  [4]]
 [[4]
  [4]]
 [[5]
  [5]]]

>>> arr1.shape
(4, 2, 1)
```

Please help I really got stuck at this.

Comment: It's not clear what should be in the 2nd dimension... just a copy? then try `np.hstack([arr, arr])`

Comment: You can't *reshape* a 4x1x1 array to a 4x2x1 array. I think @ViacheslavZ has what you want

Comment: you could also use `repeat`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [484]: arr = np.array([1, 4, 4, 5]).reshape((4, 1, 1))                                        
In [485]: np.concatenate([arr,arr],axis=1)                                                       
Out[485]: 
array([[[1],
        [1]],

       [[4],
        [4]],

       [[4],
        [4]],

       [[5],
        [5]]])
In [486]: np.repeat(arr,2,1)                                                                     
Out[486]: 
array([[[1],
        [1]],

       [[4],
        [4]],

       [[4],
        [4]],

       [[5],
        [5]]])
```

Speeds are similar; with a slight edge for the `repeat`, but not enough to fight over.  `np.hstack` is a concatenate on axis 1.